# C# this Indexer to VB.NET Me Indexer Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How would this be written in VB.NET?

```
public class Foos : ICollection<Foo> {

  private List<Foo> list;

  public Foos() {
    list = new List<Foo>();
  }

  public Foo this[int index] {
    get {
      return list[index];
    }
  }

}
```

Here is what I tried:

```
Public Class Foos
  Implements ICollection(Of Foo)

  Private list as Generic.List(Of Foo)

  Public Sub New()
    list = New Generic.List(Of Foo)()
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property Me(index As Integer) As Foo
    Get
      Return list(index)
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

Visual Studio gives a compile error at line with `Me(index As Integer)` (pointing at the **Me** keyword):

> **Keyword is not valid as an identifier.**

What do you VB coders use here?

Comment: Is that actually valid C#? Operator overloads don't use the property syntax to my knowledge

Comment: @BradleyDotNET This is valid C#. There is no operator overload here. It is an [indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: In the future, you could simply use a converter: http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have had mixed luck on the converter, and I wasn't expecting this one to convert properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Default` and something other than the reserved name `Me`:

```
  Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As Foo
    Get
      Return list(index)
    End Get
  End Property
```

`Default` signifies that the property is the, well, default property for the class, meaning that if you don;t specify the property name it will implicitly use the default property.  So it *looks* like an array indexer but is really just a method call.

You can also name it anything you want - `Item` is a fairly common name used by framework classes, but there's no magic from using the name `Item`.

Comment: Ah-ha! I was missing the `Default` keyword. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Converter tool to Convert C# to VB.NET.

http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx

```
    Public Class Foos
     Implements ICollection(Of Foo)

     Private list As List(Of Foo)

     Public Sub New()
        list = New List(Of Foo)()
     End Sub

     Public Default ReadOnly Property Item(index As Integer) As Foo
        Get
            Return list(index)
        End Get
     End Property
   End Class
```